# Как удаленно подключить к SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

Есть приложение WPF, которое с базой данных соединяется через Entity Framework. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при запуске exe файла приложения на другой компьютер, приложение удаленно подключалось к базе данных.

Comment: в чем конкретно сложности?

Comment: Приложение запущено на одном компьютере, а БД расположена на другом, так?

Comment: да. Мне нужно чтобы приложение и база данных находились на разных компьютерах.

Comment: Давайте разберем шаги. Устанавливаете базу данных. Настраиваете ее шоб можно было удалено подключиться. Далее ваше приложение настраивает подключение и работает. Один вопрос зачем вам management studio?